# What can the eigenvalues of unitary matrices tell us?

Tags: quantum-information, unitarity

I'm searching for applications where the distribution of the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix are important. Example properties of the eigenvalues could be that the eigenvalues are clustered, that they live in some half plane, that, in the case that the matrix is orthogonal, that a certain fraction are 1, etc.