# What can the eigenvalues of unitary matrices tell us?

Tags: quantum-information, unitarity

I'm searching for applications where the distribution of the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix are important. Example properties of the eigenvalues could be that the eigenvalues are clustered, that they live in some half plane, that, in the case that the matrix has real eigenvalues, that a certain fraction are 1, etc. Are there any well known areas where this is important?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644992/2451

Comment: Hi tch. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Thanks - sorry about that. I did edit it the original post, but what happens after that? The instructions said to edit it or post a new one.

Comment: FWIW, the same issue appeared [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13577/2451).

Comment: Math [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170411/uses-for-eigenvalues-of-unitary-matrices).